# String and array mixing syntax and a very rare usage

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have found very interesting but yet very strange String and array mixing up(syntax). See below code:

Example A:

```
int x = (int)(Math.random()*4 );
String n = new String[] {"FF", "RR"}[x];

System.out.println(n) ;
```

It outputs "FF" or "RR" when the random number is 0 or 1. My question is how that can happen. I am unable to understand the syntax used in Example A. I have used a very normal String array syntax just as below :

```
String s[] ;
s = new String[]{"dd", "rr"};
```

Or

```
String s [] =  {"gg", "ss"};
```

But I haven't seen the top syntax (Example A). Can someone pitch in to help me understand how the top syntax is treated and executed. Advance thanks.

Comment: `Random.nextInt(int n)` is typically considered a better way of generating a random integer (well, at least I consider it such).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String n = new String[] {"FF", "RR"}[x];
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This creates an *anonymous array* containing two elements, `"FF"` and `"RR"`. An anonymous array is a temporary object that has no name and is destroyed as soon as the statement is finished executing. That anonymous array is then indexed using the `[]` operator.

```
String n = new String[] {"FF", "RR"}[x];
                                    ^^^
```

This returns the `x`'th element of the anonymous array.

Note that there appears to be a bug in this program; if the random number causes `x` to be greater than 1, you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Elaborating on your last statement, `x` can take on any value in [0,3], both 2 and 3 will generate an exception.

Comment: easy and good explanation. I agree it throws "ArrayIndexOutofBoundException" if random number is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

`new String[] {"FF", "RR"}` is an expression of type "array of String". This is why you can assign it to `s` in

```
String[] s = new String[] {"FF", "RR"};
```

Since it's of type "array of Strings", you can use the `[]` operator on it to get the String at a given index. And you must put an `int` inside the brackets. And `x`is an `int`.

So `new String[] {"FF", "RR"}[x]` is the element at index `x` of the array `new String[] {"FF", "RR"}`. This element is of type String. So you can assign it to the variable `n`, which is also declared as a String.

That's basically the same thing as doing

```
char c = "hello".charAt(2);
```

or

```
int i = new Person().getName().substring(2).indexOf('o');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bascially the same as your second notation.

The second line is equivalent to

```
String s[]= new String[]{"FF","RR"};
String n = s[x];
```

It's just that `s` is anonymous in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

This of it like this: When you are normally access an element in a String array, what do you do?

```
String s = arr[0];
```

That gets the first element in the array. Now you are doing this:

```
String n = new String[] {"FF", "RR"}[x];
```

You are simply getting an element from the array immediately upon creation. Or, the `xth` element. Note that you program will fail if the random number is outside the bounds of the array.